# Classnames as a return type to a method?

Tags: java

Now I've been studying Java for some time now but there's a concept I'm struggling to wrap my head around. I'm used to methods like these

```
  public int something () {

}
```

I know the above method will return an Integer or a String whatever data type you want. I've recently encountered a method like these

```
public customclassname methodname(){
}
```

now I was asking myself what on earth is the return type of the above method. How do I use the returned thing to do something else?

I also saw people **passing objects to methods as parameters** like this

```
public something methodname(Customclass customclass){
}
```

What's the deal with that too? In what scenario is the above "style" necessitated and what are the pitfalls to avoid?

**Using objects instead of values** like integers or whatnot is confusing me.

Comment: The answer to your question is no different if you replaced `int` with `Integer`/`String`. Have you learned how to create your own class definitions yet?

Comment: Using Java, an inherently Object Oriented Programming Language, you should look into what Object Orientation (aka OOP) is and how to apply those concepts

Answer (score 0):

> I know the above method will return an Integer or a String whatever data type you want.

Yes, that's correct. Now add to that the fact that *classes are data types* and this should become more clear. A `Customclass` that you define is still a data type that can be the return type of a method, or the type of a value passed in as a method parameter.

For "pitfalls to avoid" you should probably read up on [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1288)